# Looping copying and pasting columns from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

This should be a relatively easy thing to do, but please forgive me since I'm new with VBA. I'm trying to automate looping through copying columns from one sheet to pasting onto another. The columns are different lengths and the offsets are different between copying and pasting.

Here's what I have so far (it times out so not sure what's going on with my loop).

```
Sub LoopEveryTwoColumns()

Dim original As Range
Dim destination As Range

Set original = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B")
Set destination = Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("A")

Dim x As Long

    For x = 1 To 3
        original.Copy (destination)
        original.Offset(0, 2).Copy (destination.Offset(0, 1))
    Next x

End Sub
```

Here's what I want it to look like. The first picture is the original range on Sheet1. The second picture is the destination range that should be copied onto Sheet2.

[image: Original Range on Sheet1]

[image: Destination Range on Sheet2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without variables it is quite simple:

```
Sub TestMe()    
    Dim x As Long    
    For x = 1 To 3
        Worksheets(1).Columns(x * 2).Copy Worksheets(2).Columns(x)
    Next x    
End Sub
```

The idea is that you need every second column - hence `x * 2`. And in the second worksheet, you need to paste it consequetively - thus `x`.

If you need to make it with variables (which is in general better), set the variables for the worksheet, not the columns:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim original As Worksheet
    Dim destination As Worksheet

    Set original = Worksheets(1)
    Set destination = Worksheets(2)

    Dim x As Long

    For x = 1 To 3
        original.Columns(x * 2).Copy destination.Columns(x)
    Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead.

```
For x = 1 To 3
    original.Columns(x+1).Copy destination.Cells(1,x)
Next x
```